# Installing TrueCrypt on dual boot Mac/Win7 laptop

Tags: windows-7, mac, multi-boot, truecrypt

A friend (not much of a technician) owns a Mac laptop with dual boot Win7/Mac.

Now he wants to encrypt the entire drive (both systems) using TrueCrypt.

I read a lot and found a lot of outdated guides and comments. Some stating it wouldn't be possible to encrypt an entire harddrive of a multi-boot system (but the window partition only).

Will the encryption wizard do the job? Are there any problems that will arise? Is there something he needs to know before starting?

Comment: I'd backup the whole disk first. I do believe that FDE on truecrypt is windows only and requires a special bootloader

Comment: So if FDE really is Windows only, he should probably use partition encryption only, right? Is it possible to encrypt both partitions (Win and Mac) one after the other or may he encrypt the Windows partition only?

Comment: I don't have a mac to test this on, so I'm not sure.

Comment: If he is using Boot Camp to boot into Windows full disk encryption should be offered by OS X.

Comment: Does FDE offered by OS X also encrypt the Windows partition? I could not find a statement confirming this.

Comment: What version of Mac OS X is he running? 10.7 and 10.8 have BootCamp which as @Ramhound says above, if it is used can encrypt the entire disk.

Comment: @Silicomancer - If Boot Camp is used OS X's boot loader handles booting into Windows, since Boot Camp is a major feature of OS X, I would assume that.

Comment: He uses Boot Camp and OS X 10.8.5. If this would work without additional tools it surely would be the best solution. Is there some ressource where I could read about how to encrypt a multi-boot Mac using the OS X FDE?

Comment: We are talking about "File Vault 2", right?